# Is it okay to call django functions through an API?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm building a project and now I'm new to VueJS I'm currently learning it. and I found that you can  make HTTP Requests on APIs using axios. And to make my project easy, Can I call functions on my views.py thru axios?

Like I'm fetching urls in urls.py to execute some functions on my backend.

Is it okay? I mean for security and best practices. etc.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You cannot call Python code through frontend javascript.

Comment: can you give some example code showing what you have in mind?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for answering, I thought it's possible to call a python code through frontend javascript. Now I will call the functions thru api endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely ok, that's what Django is for:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('my_view_function/', views.my_view_function, name='my_view_function'),
    ...
]
```

views.py:

```
def my_view_function(request):

    # unpack data:
    my_value = request.GET['my_key']

    # some logic:
    ...

    # pack response:
    response = json.dumps({
        'some_other_key' : 'some_other_value'
    })

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you use signals in django, some time ago I used signals that for when a new record is created without a field, it will be completed with the algorithm you want, for example an order and automatically placed a code, you can apply it only by pointing to  your models, when you want something more punctual.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
```

The **my_handler function** will only be called when an instance of **MyModel is saved.**

Here I leave the documentation in case you want to review it

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/